# Is there a local client like Gmail?

Tags: windows-xp, gmail, exchange

I'd love to use something with the Gmail interface for my work (Exchange) e-mails, and I don't exactly carry enough weight to convince the entire company to switch to Google Apps.

With that in mind, is there a local, not-in-the-cloud web client that supports IMAP or POP3 and has the look and feel of Gmail's web interface?  (that works on Windows XP).

Comment: I just discovered Mailplane, which looks awesome, but is OSX only unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look and feel? That depends on what look and feel you are going for. The newest Outlook from Office 2010 handles "conversations" much better now. (You can even ignore a "thread"). Also, Thunderbird has done conversations for awhile as well.

If it is the Label system you prefer. You can do Categories in 2010 Outlook and create a "Search Folder" for that Category.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm on Outlook 2007, and it's support for conversations is quite painful.  Thanks for letting me know about 2010, though!  Maybe there's hope in my future.

Comment: I use Outlook 2010 on my laptop, Thunderbird on my desktop and Clawmail on another PC. So far the new Outlook has impressed me.

Comment: Wait... is 2010 even out yet?  All I'm seeing is a pre-order:  http://store.microsoft.com/microsoft/Outlook-2010/product/B79828F2

Comment: Heh, sorry I have a Technet subscription. The RTM is out on there which is the final version. 2010 is due out this month retail.

Answer (score 0):

None that I know of.

Neither outlook nor Thunderbird have quite broken free of the "traditional email client" paradigm to te extent that gmail has done this.